# Do not connect Vdd and Vss with AD732x ADC?

Tags: analog, adc, device

According to the AD732x datasheets, especially the figure of "Equivalent Analog Input Circuit (Single-Ended)", do not connect Vdd and Vss should have no effects except on throughput rate (should be a litlle less).
So I've tried it on the [AD7323](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7323.pdf) and it's working well without Vss and Vdd (no connections) with a range of +/-10V input, but Vcc has to be at 5V and not only 3,3V (otherwise under -6V there is a saturation).
I also note that connecting Vss to 0V will normally block -10V to 0 input range due to the clamp protection.
So my questions are : how are Vss and Vdd used in these ADC so that it's possible to works without it ? And why under -6V with +/-10V input range, there is saturation with Vcc=3,3V ?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that you could leave VDD and VSS unconnected? It looks to me that they are required to be at least +/-5V for proper operation. What you're seeing is in the category of "improper operation" and all bets are off.

Comment: The "typical connection diagrams", Fig 32 and 33, do show Vdd and Vss supplies, and the Absolute Maximum Ratings table states that the input voltages must be between Vdd+0.3V and Vss-0.3 volts, so you MUST provide Vdd and Vss power supplies - they provide power to the analog input section.

Comment: Thank for your answers, but I know that, I've read with attention the datasheet to try to understand how is the circuitry inside to find answer to my 2 questions. So why I get the idea to leave Vss and Vdd unconnected : just because the famous AD7606 is also working with an input range of +/-10V, without Vss and Vdd pins ! So ... I supposed that it was possible with AD732x, and it is...

Comment: You are powering up the device thru it’s ESD input diodes. By rectifying to a cap the analog input.  Very bad  idea. Why did you think this was a good idea.

Comment: Top of the Specifications table on page 3 says "**VDD = 12 V to 16.5 V, VSS = −12 V to −16.5 V**, VCC = 2.7 V to 5.25 V, VDRIVE = 2.7 V to 5.25 V, VREF = 2.5 V to 3.0 V internal/external,
fSCLK = 10 MHz, fS = 500 kSPS, TA = TMAX to TMIN, unless otherwise noted."

Comment: Considering the figure "Equivalent Analog Input Circuit (Single-Ended)" in the datasheet, it's possible that Vss and Vdd are only protections with clamps for all inputs, and also create a better timing performance for the Track and Hold part. So I really think Vcc is the supply, not Vss and Vdd.

Comment: All monolithic CMOS integrated circuits have PN junction diodes which are often integrated into the ESD protection structures (not shown on the datasheet 'simplified diagrams' but referenced in specifications table). VDD is the top drain node, VSS is the bottom source node, VDD > everything, VSS < everything. These are not optional. What you're doing violates every spec on every page of the datasheet! The only reason it seems to be "working" in this abused state is because current is spraying around inside the die in ways the designers did not intend.

Comment: Please consider that if it's working perfectly with an input of +/-10V and Vcc=5V and Vlogic=3,3V, that means that Vss and Vdd are not the supply for this chip. It's a kind of evidence. My questions are : why, and what can be the circuitry inside to allow this behaviour ? Same as with AD7606 ?

Comment: NO, it is NOT working perfectly!!!  You are violating the datasheet specifications and drawing incorrect conclusions about what is happening. This is actua;lply makkjng me angry and I thiink  I have to sign off now

Comment: It's working perfectly, so there are reasons for that, it's not due to hazard. Pls don't become angry, a datasheet is not a law and I will not go to jail... And moreover there are contradictions in the datasheet with these Vss and Vdd if you read all the datasheet : +/5V minimum, but it's also written it can be less...

Comment: The AD7606  is a different part - it apparently has a different analog input circuit than the AD7323, so has different power requirements.  The datasheet IS the law - it defines how the part operates, and under what conditions it must be used to meet specifications.

Comment: Hum, can people who think datasheet is the law stop to answer this post please, I'm trying to understand a behaviour, not a paranormal activity. Because I have to say that it becomes ridiculous this way of thinking : moreover telling stories about suppling with the ESD protections is just not intelligent because in my case : Vss and Vdd are not connected, and are supposed to be higher than the others supplies. I'm really disapointed of some  anwers in this post : it seems that some people focus on the fingers : "When the sage points at the moon, the fool looks at his finger..."

Comment: You can certainly get interesting behavior running chips with power rails out of spec. But you can’t expect anybody to tell you what that behavior would be because the only data we have is the datasheet which is only valid for the specified voltage rails. If someone could supply the schematic of the chip innards we could make an intelligent guess but otherwise it’s just idle speculation.

Comment: Good answer td127, you are true : the chip is a black box. So my speculation is that for this chip Vss and Vdd are only used as ESD/clamp protections. In that case, I can disconnect Vss and Vdd and add external ESD protection with on inputs transzorbs to GND (so not clamps). I've done more tests today which are all confirmations of my speculation.

Comment: It seems that AD7898 is the single channel version of the AD7323. But obviously with no Vss and Vdd and here Vcc = 4.75 to 5.25V (not 2.7 to 5.25V) and the Track and Hold do not need Vdd here. I think the datasheet of AD7323 is incomplete and inaccurate, so I contact Analog Device with my questions.

Comment: @zlan The specs of a datasheet are known operating conditions recommended by the manufacturer for proper operation. The datasheet isn't the 'law' its what a designer needs to get the device to operate properly. Yes you can run the device under different conditions, will it work? There is no guarantee by the manufacturer that it will work. Don't follow the speed limit, but if you don't want to get a speeding ticket then follow it. No one can tell you what the devices unintended operation will be without knowing the design, and the manufacturer will direct you to operate the device as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device will function but it will probably not function and meet all the spec's in the datasheet (noise, current, power and/or common mode range). The lifetime of the device may also be reduced or if there were a fault it could burn up. You can run a device in any configuration, but it most likely won't work as intended. If you ran the ADC through the same battery of tests (all the tests that they use to produce the graphs and the spec table), then you will most likely find that some of them are different.

It's not surprising that the AD7323 still functions, they have probably tied the digital VCC to the internal amp (or have a regulator) so if either the analog or digital power comes up first it doesn't cause problems for the circuitry (and AGND and DGND are probably tied if they were ohmed out with a meter, or with diodes, because it says that they can't be separated by more than 0.3V this usually indicates a diode turning on). Another thing is if you tried all selectable range settings, its likely that some of them will not function.

If you want, you could run the chip without connecting Vss and Vdd and even launch it in a product (I am not condoning this, I'm just saying that its a possibility), but if the chip fails or does not work as intended then the responsibility rests on the designer especially if they don't follow manufacture recommendations.